# Importing a specific folder as a new project in Aptana doesn't work

Tags: php, eclipse, wordpress, ide, aptana

I have the following problem importing a project in Aptana Studio 3.

I have setted that my workspace is the `/var/www/` directory of my Ubuntu system.

In this directory I have installed a WordPress website that itself contains some directory including the directory that contain a specific WordPress theme, for example: `/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/`

If I try to import as **Existing Folder as New Project** the theme directory (`/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/`) in the Project Explorer I obtain an empty project named `twentytwelve` (it contains only the Connections icon)

The only way to have all the file on which I have to work is import the entire WordPress directory (`/var/www/wordpress/`) as a new project. In this way I have a project that contains all the file of the website on which I work and I can work on my theme.

But why if I import the theme directory I obtain the empty project and it work well if I import the entire website in the work-space?